# Doubts in some inequalities used in asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I was going through this recent [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/333), and I had a couple of doubts in the final analysis of complexity of the scheme (you don't need to go through the whole paper). I included three questions here, as I thought they seem to simple questions.

1. In Pg 17 (last four lines, see after equation 7), it seems that there is this inequality which is used (here, $k(n) = \sqrt{\frac{n\delta(n)}{\log n}}$ and $\delta(n) = o(n / \log n)$):

$\frac{\binom{n}{a}}{\binom{^n/_k}{^a/_k}^k} \leq (^n/_k)^k$

Can I know a proof for it?

2. Similarly, in the beginning of Pg 18, how is this possible? (the above inequality is used to get here though, $(n / k)^{k / 2}$ thing, and don't worry about the meaning of $\mathtt{ss}$)

$\mathtt{ss} \leq \sqrt{\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}-\delta(n)}}\cdot (n / k)^{k / 2} \cdot \binom{k}{2\delta(n)} \cdot 2^{(2\delta(n)+1)n / k} \leq 2^{n / 2 + o(n)}$

3. Also, this one might be a bit trivial, in Pg 17, one inequality above equation 7, the $O(n)$ term is dropped, isn't that relevant?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?  Some hints:  It seems like the first should fall relatively easily to standard Stirling type control on binomial coefficients - for example, using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients). For the second, it looks like every term in the product except the first 
is $2^{o(n)}$ - try taking the log of each one and arguing this. Third I have no clue, there's too much notation there.

Comment: Thanks @stochasticboy321 for your help. I should have figured out 2 at least. Also, thanks to [Shagnik](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/347482/shagnik) for his [notes](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/shagnik/notes/binomials.pdf) on bounds of binomial coefficients.

Comment: ^You're welcome. It would be nice if you wrote a solution as an answer below, so that someone else with a similar question could benefit in the future. Also, yeah, those notes are excellent. [This](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/043_00_JIPAM/043_00.pdf)  paper of Stanica is also at times useful, in case you want to add to your collection of binomial coefficient bounds.